# recreate an array based on options selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help solving a simple requirement.

```
<select id="my-select1">
    <option value="1">This is option 1 ({myop1}|OP)</option>
    <option value="2" selected>This is option 2 ({myop1}|OQ)</option>
    <option value="3">This is option 3 ({myop1}|OR)</option>
</select>
<select id="my-select2">
    <option value="1">This is option 1 ({myop2}|PP)</option>
    <option value="2">This is option 2 ({myop2}|PQ)</option>
    <option value="3" selected>This is option 3 ({myop2}|PR)</option>
</select>
<select id="my-select3">
    <option value="1">This is option 1 ({myop3}|QP)</option>
    <option value="2">This is option 2 ({myop3}|QQ)</option>
    <option value="3" selected>This is option 3 ({myop3}|QR)</option>
</select>
```

See the HTML above, I want to recreate my array:

```
combo = ["abc-{myop1}-{myop2}", "def-{myop2}"];
```

INTO

```
combo = ["abc-OQ-PR", "def-PR"];
```

based on the selected options.

**Another thing to note is that I cannot simply change the value of the options of the select box, meaning to say the HTML is somewhat as it is, if it would help, the only part i can restructure on that HTML is the text content between `<option></option>`**

I'm not sure, but I'm already spending a couple of hrs just to solve this problem. Maybe due to my limited jQuery knowledge.

Please help. thanks

Comment: So `abc-{myop1}-{myop2}` is kind of a template and you want to "insert" the values from the select box?

Comment: Yes, the new array will be based on the selections from the select box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the selected values into an associative array:

```
var pattern = {};
var s = $('select option:selected').each(function(){
    var m = /\((.*?)\|(.*)\)/.exec($(this).text());
    pattern[m[1]] = m[2];
});
```

Then you can replace each place holder in each string in the array with the corresponding value:

```
combo = $.map(combo, function(e){
    return e.replace(/\{.*?\}/g, function(m){
        return pattern[m];
    });
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/C97ma/](http://jsfiddle.net/C97ma/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided I'm don't get it 100% I guess. But whatever you're trying to do, I guess jQuerys `.map()` and `$.map()` would help you here.

Like

```
var arr = $('select').find('option:selected').map(function(index, elem) {
    return elem.textContent || elem.text;
}).get();
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/78/

Within the **callback** you can modify/match the text in any way you want/need. In your case I could imagine you want to use a regular expression to match the selected strings and recreate those somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I figure you're using javascript for combining those (it can be done with PHP also)..
You need references to your selects, e.g. :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   a=document.getElementById("myselect").options[1];
</script>
```

This will assign the 2nd option value from the 'myselect' select element to the variable 'a'

Answer (score 0):

To begin with I would change the values in the select box like this:

```
<select id="my-select1">
    <option value="OP">This is option 1 ({myop1}|OP)</option>
    <option value="OQ" selected>This is option 2 ({myop1}|OQ)</option>
    <option value="OR">This is option 3 ({myop1}|OR)</option>
</select>
<select id="my-select2">
    <option value="PP">This is option 1 ({myop2}|PP)</option>
    <option value="PQ">This is option 2 ({myop2}|PQ)</option>
    <option value="PR" selected>This is option 3 ({myop2}|PR)</option>
</select>
<select id="my-select3">
    <option value="QP">This is option 1 ({myop3}|QP)</option>
    <option value="QQ">This is option 2 ({myop3}|QQ)</option>
    <option value="QR" selected>This is option 3 ({myop3}|QR)</option>
</select>
```

Now to update your array:

```
var comboDef = ["abc-{myop1}-{myop2}", "def-{myop2}"];
var combo = ["abc-{myop1}-{myop2}", "def-{myop2}"];

function updateArray() {
    combo = comboDef;
    for (i in combo)
    {
        combo[i] = combo[i].replace("{myop1}",document.getElementById("my-select1").value);
        combo[i] = combo[i].replace("{myop2}",document.getElementById("my-select2").value);
        combo[i] = combo[i].replace("{myop3}",document.getElementById("my-select3").value);
    }
}
```

Of course, this could be done better with proper arrays (if you gave your select boxes the same name you could iterate through them using `document.getElementsByName()`). The basic idea is the `replace` though which I trust is what you're looking for.